# How do I make a method work in my class in Java

Tags: java

Hi I have a robot which I need to tell it to move a certain number of times forward by saying forward 5. I have the method, I just need to get it to work in my class. Here is the method:

```
public void moveNumOfTimes(int num)
   {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       int i=0;

       while(i<num)    {
        if (this.frontIsClear()){ // if the front is NOT clear the robot should not move, otherwise will collide into the wall
             this.move();
        }
        i++; // same as i=i+1;
    }
     //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   }
```

How do I enter that in my program? Is it like this?

```
moveNumOfTimes(int num);
```

Hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: You call it, the same way you call the `fontIsClear()` or `move()` methods, except this time you specify the number of times as an argument (e.g. `moveNumOfTimes(5);`). If you have problems with this, you should read Java tutorials on the web before moving on with your project.

Comment: There are lots of good tutorials out there. It looks like you want to read from the command line.  Give this article a read:  http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010005

Comment: I understand that but I am meant to enter it in the command line to tell it to run five times instead of inputting it every time I want it to go forward a certain number of steps.

Comment: @Tom do you know how to use the Scanner class?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Scanner object to take input from the console.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You can implement like this.

```
class Robot{

public static void main(String args[]){

Scanner sc = new Scanner();
int numOfSteps = sc.nextInt(); //This line takes a integer input from the user

YourClassName r = new YourClassName();
//DO any initialization operations here

r.moveNumOfTimes(numOfSteps); 

//Post movement operations come here

}
```

You can learn more on scanner [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I enter that in my program? Is it like this?

```
moveNumOfTimes(int num);
```

Yes, you could use something similar to this if you were trying to pass a command in from another method call. Something like:

```
public void Control(int moveNumber) {
    ... some other code, do some other stuff...
    moveNumOfTimes(moveNumber); //Here you are passing a parameter value to your original method;
}
```

Or you could control it directly with another method like:

```
public void moveFive() {
    moveNumOfTimes(5);
}
```

More likely, however, you wouldn't want to hardcode a method but rather call your original method directly through your [Main method](https://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html).

```
public static void main(String [ ] args) {
   Robot r = new Robot();
   r.moveNumOfTimes(5); //Here you have moved your new robot!
}
```

And if you really want to get fancy, look into working with the [`System`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) and [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) classes so you can prompt your user to tell the robot how much to move:

```
 public static void main(String [ ] args) {
         Robot r = new Robot();
         Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("How far should the robot move?"); //Output to the console window
         int input = reader.nextInt();  //Reads the next int value
         r.moveNumOfTimes(input); //Calls your method using the scanned input
 }
```